# positioning starting location of Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to position the emulated phone in Android Studio virtual device.  Launching the Nexus S API 21 virtual device, places the emulation at the top of top of the screen and I'm unable to get the Windows frame to move the emulation or to minimize the device.  So it is fixed at the top.
I have tried to modify the file “emulator-user.ini” for this simulation .  I can change the window’s. Y location to lets say 530.  When the emulator graphics becomes visible I see it on my monitor at what I assume is the Y 500 location for a quick flash and then it quickly shifts back to the top of the screen where y equals 0 and I am unable to position the device.  Is there some way to set the starting location?

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your Android Emulator by connecting to it via `telnet`:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5560 device

$ telnet localhost 5560
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
window scale 0.75
OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on this website by rephrasing the question in a google search:

Press the Alt-Space keys and you should get the window with the option allowing you to move the emulator window. Then move it e.g. using keyboard arrows. It works for me on Windows 7.
Credit goes to JeriB on April 9